# Unable to show annotations in geofire getlocation callback

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, geofire

I want to show annotations on the locations I get from my geofire database but even after writing the code and not getting any error no annotations are visible on the map. 
My variable is

```
var vendorStore: Dictionary<String,Int>
```

My code in viewDidLoad

```
for (key,_) in KeyValue{
        geoFireKeyValue.getLocationForKey(key, withCallback: { (location, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("An error occurred getting the location for \"firebase-hq\": \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            } else if location != nil {
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                self.lat = (location?.coordinate.latitude)!
                self.long = (location?.coordinate.longitude)!
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.lat, longitude: self.long)
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                self.mapView.showAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations, animated: true)

            } else {
                print("GeoFire does not contain a location for \"firebase-hq\"")
            }
        })
    }
```

I am successfully getting the latitude and longitude in print statement as well but still no annotations are showing up. I tried moving the code else outside the for loop (just to check if any annotation show up) with some hard coded lat long coordinates and the annotation showed successfully. But still they aren't showing up when set in the geofire function within the loop (also not showing up in the loop outside the geofire function even with hard coded values). So kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: The problem is still unresolved

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The main problem was that I was sending the data from the previous view controller. That view controller was changed before the data was sent from the previous controller. So the solution is to make sure that data is set in the variable of the next view controller before the view actually appears. That's what I am trying to achieve now.